# Buttons with alternate style not responding to ngIf

Tags: angular

Context: I have a dialog that is shown in many places and I need two type of dialog buttons

- default: color="accent", ENTER presses this button, click as usual
- regular: no color specified, click as usual

And for that I decided to create a DialogButtonComponent

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="isDefault else regularButton">
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close class="action" color="accent" #btnFocus [autofocus]="btnFocus.focus()"
        (click)="clickHandler()" (keyup.enter)="clickHandler()">
        DEF-{{text}}
    </button>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #regularButton>
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close class="action nonDefault" (click)="clickHandler()">
        {{text}}
    </button>
</ng-template>
```

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'wss-dialog-button',
  templateUrl: './dialog-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-button.component.scss']
})
export class DialogButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() text: string = '';
  @Input() isDefault: boolean = false;
  @Output() click: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.isDefault);
  }

  public clickHandler() {
    this.click.emit(true);
  }

}
```

When I try to use this in a dialog I have a weird behavior, both buttons are being shown as default

[image]

How can that be when the condition is the opposite

- on 1st button `isDefault="{{!data.confirmIsDefault}}"`
- on 2nd button `isDefault="{{data.confirmIsDefault}}"`

```html
<mat-dialog-actions class="buttons">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!data.saveFunction; else showSaveAndContinue">
        <wss-dialog-button isDefault="{{!data.confirmIsDefault}}" text="1+{{data.cancel}}" (click)="onCancelClick()">
        </wss-dialog-button>
    </ng-container>
    <wss-dialog-button isDefault="{{data.confirmIsDefault}}" text="2+{{data.closeOrConfirm}}" (click)="cancelOrClose()">
    </wss-dialog-button>
    <ng-template #showSaveAndContinue>
        <wss-dialog-button isDefault="{{!data.confirmIsDefault}}" text="3+{{data.saveAndContinue}}"
            (click)="onSaveAndContinueClick()">
        </wss-dialog-button>
    </ng-template>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a certain magic in this website, as soon as you post a question you find the solution

What I needed was to pass the input parameters with square brackets

- before `isDefault="{{!data.confirmIsDefault}}"`
- now `[isDefault]="!data.confirmIsDefault"`

```html
<mat-dialog-actions class="buttons">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!data.saveFunction; else showSaveAndContinue">
        <wss-dialog-button [isDefault]="!data.confirmIsDefault" [text]="data.cancel" (click)="onCancelClick()">
        </wss-dialog-button>
    </ng-container>
    <wss-dialog-button [isDefault]="data.confirmIsDefault" [text]="data.closeOrConfirm" (click)="cancelOrClose()">
    </wss-dialog-button>
    <ng-template #showSaveAndContinue>
        <wss-dialog-button [isDefault]="!data.confirmIsDefault" [text]="data.saveAndContinue"
            (click)="onSaveAndContinueClick()">
        </wss-dialog-button>
    </ng-template>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```